# API Call - Having Difficulty Referencing Public List From Deserialized JSON

Tags: c#, json, list

I'm trying to understand how to use the data from an API call.  I can reference everything in "Booking" except the contents of "Item" - specifically "startTime".

```
var APIContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(APIContent);
```

```
public class Booking
{
    public string bookingReference { get; set; }
    public string uniqueId { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int customerId { get; set; }
    public double total { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public List<object> customerFlags { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int productId { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string bookingDate { get; set; }
    public string startTime { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Booking> bookings { get; set; }
}
```

As mentioned, I need to pull the string from "startTime" but I'm unsure how to reference it. When stepping through code I can see the data is there.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

````
    {
        "bookings": [
            {
                "bookingReference": "13092675",
                "uniqueId": "1537d669-1a11-487a-b132-b9198a822956",
                "createdDate": "2024-03-10T18:26:16.943Z",
                "status": "Paid",
                "name": "Test Data",
                "customerId": 03737676,
                "total": 321.35,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "productId": 188460,
                        "quantity": 20,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15",
                        "startTime": "11:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "productId": 180344,
                        "quantity": 20,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15"
                    },
                    {
                        "productId": 180343,
                        "quantity": 20,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15"
                    },
                    {
                        "productId": 180310,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15"
                    },
                    {
                        "productId": 111193,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15"
                    },
                    {
                        "productId": 194193,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15"
                    },
                    {
                        "productId": 194194,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15"
                    },
                    {
                        "productId": 194194,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15"
                    },
                    {
                        "productId": 194693,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15"
                    },
                    {
                        "productId": 194694,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15"
                    },
                    {
                        "productId": 194710,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "bookingDate": "2024-03-15"
                    }
                ],
                "customerFlags": []
            },
    ```
````

Comment: can you post an example of the json that is being returned too please

Comment: Yes of course, apologies for not having done so originally.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference `startTime` from the *first* item in the *first* booking like this:

```
var startTime = myDeserializedClass.bookings[0].items[0].startTime;
```

Since `bookings` and `items` are `List`s, you can access them by index.
E.g. to iterate over start times of all items of all bookings, you can do this:

```
for (var bookingIndex = 0; bookingIndex < myDeserializedClass.bookings.Count; ++bookingIndex)
{
    var booking = myDeserializedClass.bookings[bookingIndex];
    for (var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < booking.items.Count; ++itemIndex)
    {
        var startTime = booking.items[itemIndex].startTime;
    }
}
```

If you want to extract the start time from each item in each booking into a collection you can use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/)

```
var startTimes = myDeserializedClass.bookings.SelectMany(booking => booking.items.Select(item => item.startTime)).ToList();
```